# Spring 3 + JPA + TomCat 7

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, jpa

I am learning more about Spring and now my task is to build a web application that connects to a database, but I am stuck with the EntityManager injection, here is my files:

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate- 
    validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- LOG4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EL API 1.0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP API 2.1 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet API 2.5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL API 1.2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="2.5">
<display-name>contas</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Declaracao do servlet do Spring MVC abaixo-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/cartorio</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc- 
3.0.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring- 
beans.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring- 
context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.caelum.contas" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Create default configuration for Hibernate -->

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/cartorio"
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Tomcat server.xml

```
<GlobalNamingResources>

<Resource name="jdbc/cartorio"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="root"
          password="PASSWORD"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cartorio"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          initialSize="20"
          maxWaitMillis="15000"
          maxTotal="75"
          maxIdle="20"
          maxAge="7200000"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          validationQuery="select 1"
          />

</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Tomcat context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/cartorio"
    global="jdbc/cartorio"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

This setup is working, although, when I try to add this to my spring-context:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The error `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl` apears. As far as I know, this is the code that will make the injection possible, but it's not working. There is another option to connect the JPA to the datasource of Tomcat server?

**Edit 1:** 
@DevSpace bring me something important, I was using the wrong `jpaVendorAdapter`, now I've changed it and the error is: `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'` `IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}`. Do I need to have a `persistence.xml`? How could I write it to get the Tomcat's datasource?

**Edit 2:** 
After adding the `persistence.xml` to `src/main/resources`, the project could go running. Now I'm going to look after the injection thing that is not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared hibernate as persistence provider implementation in the pom.xml. But you defined the `ntityManagerFactoryBean`to use `OpenJpaVendorAdapter` for which you haven't declared any dependencies.

You can try to use the following on `entityManagerFactoryBean` definition:

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
</property>
```

Comment: I didn't realize about that, thank you. Unfortunately, now I am having another error, I'm going to update the question